# Open link from notification sent from parse.com Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to push a specific link (using JSON) from parse.com to my app.  When I send example.com/breaking_Somethign.html my app opens to www.example.com.  I guess I need to do something in my AppDelegate.swift file.  Can anyone tell me what i need to add.

Comment: what does "my app opens to www.example.com." mean?

Comment: it opens the default webview.

Comment: It's a UIwebview app so safari runs in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below code to the AppDelegate.swift and then handle the push using PFPush.handlePush

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

PFPush.handlePush()

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you walk me through it like I am 5?

Comment: To be completely honest, I haven't played with Parse pushes and don't remember much more than the above answer. I bet you could find something on YouTube or here on StackOverflow for more.